# Does JSESSIONID on coldfusion 11 supposed to change all the time?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have ColdFusion 11 with 2 instance, with Sticky Sessions and Session Replication.

I noticed that JSESSIONID changes every time I close and open the browser is that supposed to be like this? Shouldn't the JSESSIONID be the same while my session is not cleared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike using ColdFusion sessions (CFID/CFTOKEN) where a session can be resumed after a browser is closed and reopened, J2EE sessions cannot. While technically the session is still open on the server (until it times out), it cannot be accessed again by a browser client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Carl. So what would be the best way to keep some user session/cookies, for example: I want to store if the users is already logged in. But since the cookies and sessions are not available.

Comment: You can always create your own cookies using `<cfcookie>` to store simple user values.